# Python Substring Search

Tags: python, search, substring

I am looking for an efficient search strategy (to be implemented in python) to have queries like

> quibrofo

match string list entries like

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

Typical examples for this kind of searches would be common code completion assistants. Any kind of preprocessing or indexing of the data would be welcome as well since read access to the string list is significantly more frequent then write access.

Comment: you could transform that into a regex that would look like `q.*u.*i.*b.*r.*o.*f.*o.*` which would match what your expression matches. Unless you have more constraints that you have not mentioned?

Comment: Maybe you could use a Trigram Index. There's an article about it [here](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp4.html)

Comment: Great thanks for the hints and great article by the way on Google code search. Haven't read it complete yet but using 2 and 3- grams in such a inverted index would at least narrow the search down to a set of candidate solutions. A regexp could then do the details. I'll give it a try and post the results here. Thanks a lot!